# running svn on cygwin with SYSTEM account: SSL handshake failed: SSL error code -1/1/336032856

Tags: svn, ssl, jenkins, cygwin

I have the following problem under windows server 2008 R2 enterprise, running through cygwin the following code monitored by Jenkins:

```
svn co --trust-server-cert --non-interactive --username=xxx --password=xxxx https://xxx/testprojects C:/source/testprojects
```

That results in the following error message in Jenkins log:

```
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://xxx/testprojects'
svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'https://xxx/testprojects': SSL handshake failed: SSL error code -1/1/336032856 (https://xxx)
```

Jenkins is running under the SYSTEM acount. 
I have tried `del %APPDATA%/Subversion/auth`, the result is the same. Also removing the --trust-server-cert gave no changes.

Precodintions: windows server 2008 RE2 (windows 7), cygwin 1.7.9(0.237/5/3), Jenkins as service (no idea how to check the version at the moment)
Reproduction Steps:

1. Open cmd as admin
2. Gain System acount using the [PsExec.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) -i -s -d CMD
3. In the SYSTEM cmd call cygwin --login
4. try to svn checkout into some directory
5. observe the SSL handshake failed: SSL error

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the "xxx" in `https://xxx/testprojects` from DNS to IP or vice versa (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8351174/1996150).

This solved the same error (in a different environment, svn version 1.7.10) for me.

In my case the problem appeared only in svn (browser and openssl opened the https url, but svn returned the error), so I think it was a mix of svn issue and server certificate recognition.

If this do not solve the problem it may be a different one, but you can test SSL connection with

```
openssl s_client -connect xxx:443
```

Note: in my case I also tried to delete the current server certificate into `~/.subversion/auth/svn.ssl.server` but didn't work...

Comment: For me it was lack of access rights. After the admin added me in the access user list the error was gone...